# An internal error occurred during runtime. Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

WARNING [2] include(somepath/templates_c/%%B0^B01^B019F522%%login.htm.php) 
[function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory on Line No 1871 in somepath/Smarty.class.php
Error!: An internal error occurred during runtime.

Any body please tell me why this error is occuring..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your cache has been corrupted or isn't working correctly.  templates_c is the cache folder.

Remove all the files in templates_c

Also, make sure that the permissions of templates_c are set correctly.  I believe that folder needs read/write and maybe also execute permissions

Answer (score 0):

Obviously there is a file missing: `templates_c/%%B0^B01^B019F522%%login.htm.php`

Perhaps this is happening, because you have some non-ascii chars in your filename, and your OS and/or php implementation can't work with this?

Or for some reason smarty believes it already compiled a file when it is not. So I would try do delete the whole folder with the compiled templates. And let Smarty do a complete rebuild.